# How can I overwrite the automatically calculated kid when importing a JWK from PEM

Tags: node.js, jwt, jwk, jwe, node-jose

I am trying to create a JWE Token using the node-jose library's `createEncrypt` method. The problem is, I want to set the `kid` to a certain value. But when importing the key using the `jose.JWK.asKey` method, it's automatically calculating the `kid` and won't let me change/set it. Here is the sample code:

```
const { JWK, JWE } = require('node-jose');
encrypt = async (raw, format = 'compact', contentAlg = "A128CBC-HS256", alg = "RSA-OAEP-256") => {
    let _publicKey = `-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAxO+O52a1eAkbYatqpPAk
vhTz5VAdNloWhbmAmwPQl9202VKxU+yOCbwZSU8NqwVubHMgnxdycgJw+zGslXgz
zHPpmA5evOY2AVjpcE9avKfp523M5gxOaAnQCxat6KxORIJWLSF84EUtrzLIxgle
bvDyhfoHMGVSYiP89UQPTR+uu6irFRkdu2zFDPOx2/4XdtyAbJlWdj4Fes0v3CcA
/jDO9EmwVEiySCuagLWnrvHvCV0mCDN167JSVjeeKZy4Q36WyF0VqytxmW+mXn+m
IfcLlj5vXSXp81pI1Iyg86KZtW3A6dP8QuRlYwHJU7Z+m7AeIHtC+ol0/eBPYPwk
PQIDAQAB
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----`
    let publicKey = await JWK.asKey(_publicKey, "pem");
    publicKey.kid = "932ea6bb-2623-4dc3-96b1-c4be61e97569";
    console.log(publicKey)
    const buffer = Buffer.from(JSON.stringify(raw))
    const encrypted = await JWE.createEncrypt({ format: format, contentAlg: contentAlg, fields: { alg: alg, iat: (new Date().getTime()), exp: 30000} }, publicKey)
        .update(buffer).final();
    return encrypted;
}
let raw = {
    "mobileNumber": "1234567890",
    "customerId": "000000000",
    "sessionId": "3a600342-a7a3-4c66-bbd3-f67de5d7096f",
};
encrypt(raw).then((data)=> {console.log(data)})
```

Here is the encrypted JWE Token generated:

```
eyJhbGciOiJSU0EtT0FFUC0yNTYiLCJpYXQiOjE2NDAyNDU0NzY5ODEsImV4cCI6MzAwMDAsImVuYyI6IkExMjhDQkMtSFMyNTYiLCJraWQiOiI1bUxtdmVHdng0RHVucGlfTnBhajhxZlByRHNDYW9NV29JeWRoM003SzA4In0.SUpO7X0XXbkqQtNGVvLMNo6oGi1GrTzAR1FtXlL8ngg9Uvd91nkLiRqgcmjKBBEE1M330WV_HrUYNs2NVRcXTDcr41fSwvHSu7veK_YDj-m73LoMKlmojeB6GIRUIXIw7oaqgFSOSb_Xgq_zwG9WGa07h2OgOzeFxKNJCvt1J2i_v2Tt61yyet0hdMinT78whDGgf_JW4LUSaXY9wsqsuQSDkKWFLvxHqNmq7nGPLpgEJjm1GPF0slPvdWsARsMEttbPK9VpoMUvMcqy5bWVWSmj2MEGTVw6ua-uFw9fEgyn095wl-s8lEfZFkFaiFN7ps5VwqVV2tihpnYrCVIYAA.jxR4Gw_Gcy9Sexw-wMBKtQ.TzugQZCFgQiolIBc2FAEQ0ZbvNdPFzE2z0m9cFxWQtADEijOCzQjZreVvnsVjHFXdP_w-YcnCbmKXkwalWnFMo7wkjuuJ0fAsTfTOEiBjuIPvMa0k04C97Rc4ZYszzzL7xxwW0RnqoNxiQMkea3H0A.qAqgcg_DLV1vHzb0EIq-9A
```

If you check this on [jwt.io](https://jwt.io), you can see the `kid` is already calculated & set. How can I set/change the `kid` here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The kid is calculated automatically, when it's not known during the import:

> When importing or generating a key that does not have a "kid" defined, a "SHA-256" thumbprint is calculated and used as the "kid".

(see https://github.com/cisco/node-jose#obtaining-a-keys-thumbprint)

But in the call to `JWK.asKey`, you can pass an additional parameter `extras`, that sets values for existing fields or contains additional fields for the JWK.
For your use case, you can set a `kid` as a JSON object

```
let kid = "932ea6bb-2623-4dc3-96b1-c4be61e97569";
let publicKey = await JWK.asKey(_publicKey, "pem", {"kid":kid});
console.log(publicKey.toJSON())
```

Output:

```
{
  kty: 'RSA',
  kid: '932ea6bb-2623-4dc3-96b1-c4be61e97569',
  n: 'xO-O52a1eAkbYatqpPAkvhTz5VAdNloWhbmAmwPQl9202VKxU-yOCbwZSU8NqwVubHMgnxdycgJw-zGslXgzzHPpmA5evOY2AVjpcE9avKfp523M5gxOaAnQCxat6KxORIJWLSF84EUtrzLIxglebvDyhfoHMGVSYiP89UQPTR-uu6irFRkdu2zFDPOx2_4XdtyAbJlWdj4Fes0v3CcA_jDO9EmwVEiySCuagLWnrvHvCV0mCDN167JSVjeeKZy4Q36WyF0VqytxmW-mXn-mIfcLlj5vXSXp81pI1Iyg86KZtW3A6dP8QuRlYwHJU7Z-m7AeIHtC-ol0_eBPYPwkPQ',
  e: 'AQAB'
}
```

Comment: does this have any effect on the output of JWE? I mean does this affect the Encryption at all?

Comment: the resulting JWE will have the kid value in the header that you set here, which is what you want. Besides that, there is no other effect. Just put the code snippet above into your code and see the result.